# How to query for sub-document in an array with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema of Project that looks like this:

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    Required: true,
    trim: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
},

devices: [{
    name: {type: String, Required: true},
    number: {type: String, trim: true},
    deck: {type: String},
    room: {type: String},
    frame: {type: String}
}],

cables: {
    type: Array
},
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
adminsID: {
    type: Array
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

I want to query an object from array of "devices".
I was able to add, delete and display all sub-documents from this array but I found it really difficult to get single object that matches _id criteria in the array.

The closest I got is this (I'm requesting: '/:id/:deviceID/edit' where ":id" is Project ObjectId.

```
let device = await Project.find("devices._id": req.params.deviceID).lean()
console.log(device)
```

which provides me with below info:

```
[
{
_id: 6009cfb3728ec23034187d3b,
cables: [],
adminsID: [],
name: 'Test project',
description: 'Test project description',
user: 5fff69af08fc5e47a0ce7944,
devices: [ [Object], [Object] ],
createdAt: 2021-01-21T19:02:11.352Z,
__v: 0
}
]
```

I know this might be really trivial problem, but I have tested for different solutions and nothing seemed to work with me. Thanks for understanding

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can filter only single object from the devices array:

```
 Project.find({"devices._id":req.params.deviceID  },{ name:1,  devices: { $elemMatch:{ _id:req.params.deviceID } }})
```

Comment: Could you please explain what does "name: 1" do? Unfortunately this doesn't work perfectly for me, but at least it provides me parent document with single device object.

Comment: it shall give you the name of the document from where the array element is taken , you can remove it , I just added for clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` into projection or query stage into `find`, whatever you want it works:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "id": 1,
  "devices": { "$elemMatch": { "id": 1 } }
},{
  "devices.$": 1
})
```

or

```js
db.collection.find({
  "id": 1
},
{
  "devices": { "$elemMatch": { "id": 1 } }
})
```

Examples [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qP3tr0aP8k_) and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PDmVU39Gtl0)

Using mongoose is the same query.

```js
yourModel.findOne({
  "id": req.params.id
},
{
  "devices": { "$elemMatch": { "id": req.params.deviceID } }
}).then(result => {
  console.log("result = ",result.name)
}).catch(e => {
  // error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use aggregate if you wish to get the device alone. This will return an array

```
Project.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$devices" },
  { "$match": { "devices._id": req.params.deviceID } },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: "$devices.name",
      // Other fields
    }
  }
])
```

You either await this or use .then() at the end.

Or you could use findOne() which will give you the Project + devices with only a single element

Or find, which will give you an array of `object` with the `_id` of the project and a single element in devices

```
Project.findOne({"devices._id": req.params.deviceID}, 'devices.$'})
.then(project => {
   console.log(project.devices[0])
})
```

Comment: Code:

let device = await Project.findOne({
            "devices._id": req.params.deviceID},
            '$devices.$')

Gives me MongoDB error:
MongoError: Positional projection '$devices.$' does not match the query document.

Comment: Yeah right, there is no $ on devices, my bad

Answer (score 0):

For now I worked it around with:

```
let project = await Project.findById(req.params.id).lean()
let device = project.devices.find( _id => req.params.deviceID)
```

It provides me with what I wanted but I as you can see I request whole project. Hopefuly it won't give me any long lasting troubles in the future.